# A set of vector where $y\leq x$ is closed under the one norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I was given $F=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y \leq x\}$. I want to prove that F is closed using the one norm.

I proceed by trying to prove that complement of $F$ is open, that is the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y>x\}$.

I let $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathscr{c}(F)$, so I get $x_2>x_1$ for all $x_1, x_2$.

Then I let $r=x_2-x_1$, which means $r>0$. I consider $a \in B(x,r)$, and try to prove that $a\in \mathscr{c}(F)$.

Can we say that $d(x,a)<r$? I tried to do that but it doesn't get me anywhere. Some help please?

Comment: $d(x,a) < r$ is exactly the condition defining $B(x,r)$. So you can say that. Can you deduce from $d(x,a) < r$ that $a_2 > a_1$?

Comment: I usedthe eucledian norm, but didnt get to a statement where I can define the relationship

Comment: Ah, I thought "one norm" as in $\lVert (x,y)\rVert_1 = \lvert x\rvert +\lvert y\rvert$. With the Euclidean norm, you'd need to take $B(x, r/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Oh, ok. So you can do it in any kind of norm, just have to use the right ball size. How do you define the distance between the vector x and a with the one norm though?

Comment: $d(x,a) = \lVert x-a\rVert_1 = \lvert x_1-a_1\rvert + \lvert x_2-a_2\rvert$, and that yields $a_2 - a_1 = x_2-x_1 + \bigl((x_1-a_1) - (x_2-a_2)\bigr) \geqslant x_2 - x_1 - (\lvert x_1-a_1\rvert + \lvert x_2-a_2\rvert) = r - \lVert x-a\rVert_1 > 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  
i'm sorry if I keep bothering you. I've been thingking about the ball with radius r/2√ that you said and tried to figure out how it would work. But i couldn't do it. I'm sorry i'm so bad at tjis :'(

Comment: The crucial point is that for $s,t \geqslant 0$, you have $s+t \leqslant \sqrt{2}\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$. With that, you have $a_2-a_1\geqslant x_2-x_1- (\lvert x_1-a_1\rvert+\lvert x_2-a_2) \geqslant x_2-x_1-\sqrt{2}\lVert x-a\rVert = r-\sqrt{2}\lVert x-a\rVert > 0$ similar to the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$-norm. To see the inequality, you can invoke the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $1\cdot s + 1 \cdot t \leqslant \sqrt{1^2+1^2}\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$, or you can square it to get $(s+t)^2\leqslant 2(s^2+t^2)\iff 2st\leqslant s^2+t^2\iff 0\leqslant(s-t)^2$.

Comment: I hope that clarifies it. If not, you'll need to explain where your difficulties lie. I'll happily explain further, but would need to know what to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a_2 - a_1 = a_2 - x_2 + x_2 - x_1 + x_1 - a_1$.